# How to model ACLs?

Tags: authorization, access-control

There are different kinds of ACLs I've generally implemented:

1. Does a user have access to a resourcetype(API)?
2. Does a user have access to a resource(Object)?
3. Does a resource have access to another resource?
4. Is a resourcetype supported for a resource?
5. Restrict outcome of one metaresoucetype(Seach) based on restrictions on resourcetype.

Except for 1, everything has generally been modeled at the application layer, while (1) is answered by traditional authn/authz mechanisms. This grows immensely complex as the types of resources and resources themselves increase. Since these questions are quite similar, is there a good way to model a general purpose solution to the above class of problems? If so, what are some well known implementations/architectures?

Comment: There are many such models already in existence.  Every operating system has one, for example.  ASP.NET MVC has an [RBAC that is extensible](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875547/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NET).   What did you have in mind?  The one ring to rule them all?

Comment: Precisely that. RBAC is still from the PoV of user and resources, not resources and resources.

Comment: What does it mean for a resource to have rights to another resource? Resources by definition are inactive blobs. All it can possibly mean is that if User A has access to resource B, they also have access of some kind to resource C. That can be achieved by simply giving User A access to resource C. Generally these dependencies are managed through a Group. The group having both resource permissions and Users. If you need an automated system to have rights to resources, you would generally solve that by provisioning that system with a user account with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Better example, in transportation, a vehicle can be associated w/ pickup and drop request created at one location to another, if the vehicle is allowed to be associated w/ both locations.